# Handling datalist with angularjs (1.3)

Tags: angularjs

(i am AngularJS/JS noob)
I am trying to create an auto complete drop down with html input data list. The list should hold json objects and i want to show the user only one attribute of them.
the data list is part of a form. on submit i want to "know"/sent the selected object as json.
here is what i have so far (actual i have 2 drop downs and i want sent an object nesting the 2 selected objects):
html:

```
        <form ng-controller="registerUserToProjectController" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user">user</label>
                <input type="text" list="users" class="form-control" ng-model="fields.user" />
                <datalist id="users">
                    <option ng-repeat="user in usersList" value="{{user}}">{{user.name}} ({{user.role}})</option>
                </datalist>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project">project</label>
                <input type="text" list="projects" class="form-control" ng-model="fields.project" />
                <datalist id=projects>
                    <option ng-repeat="project in projectsList" value="{{project}}">{{project.name}}</option>
                </datalist>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">register!</button>
            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" ng-value="result" />
        </form>
```

angular:

```
app.controller('registerUserToProjectController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.projectsList = [];
    $http.get(rootUrl + '/timetracker/project/all').success(function(response) {
        $scope.projectsList = response;
    });
    $scope.usersList = [];
    $http.get(rootUrl + '/timetracker/user/all').success(function(response) {
        $scope.usersList = response;
    });
    $scope.submit = function(){
        var data = {
                    "user" : $scope.fields.user,
                    "project" : $scope.fields.project
                    };

        $scope.result ="?";
        $http.post(rootUrl + "/timetracker/usersprojects", data).success(
                function(answer, status) {
                    $scope.result = status;
                }).error(function(answer, status) {
            $scope.result = status;
        });
    }
});
```

There ar 2 problems with this:

- the dropdown shows data as json (the value) - i want only certain fields
- the object i created is invalid. It looks:

  {

  "user":"{\"id\":6,\"self\":null,\"name\":\"manager\",\"role\":\"MANAGER\"}",

  "project":"{\"id\":8,\"self\":null,\"name\":\"p2\",\"description\":\"2nd\"}"

  }

but it should look this way:

```
{
"user" : {"id":6,"self":null,"name":"manager","role":"MANAGER"},
"project" : {"id":3,"self":null,"name":"project1","description":"important"}
}
```

So how to fix this?

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KphYchaDRcIGXwRLGVGS?p=preview) (as requested - i am absolute js noob so sorry in advance)
The code has slightly change, problem remains.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use a `<datalist>` like a `<select>`.  In a `<datalist>`, only the `<option value="...">` part is used, not the rest.  So the `value` must contain the text shown in the `<input>` field.

Change your HTML to this:

```
<datalist id="users">
    <option ng-repeat="user in usersList" value="{{user}}">
</datalist>
```

and

```
<datalist id=projects>
    <option ng-repeat="project in projectsList" value="{{project}}">
</datalist>
```

Then the `value` needs to locate the entry in your `usersList` or `projectsList` arrays so you need to create a new variable like this:

```
$scope.projectsList = {};
$http.get(rootUrl + '/timetracker/project/all').success(function(response) {
    for (var i=0; i<response.length; ++i)
        $scope.projectsList[response[i].name] = response[i]
});
$scope.usersList = {};
$http.get(rootUrl + '/timetracker/user/all').success(function(response) {
    for (var i=0; i<response.length; ++i)
        $scope.usersList[response[i].name + ' ' + response[i].role] = response[i]
});
```

Finally, change your `submit` function to this:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    var data = {
                "user" : $scope.usersList[$scope.fields.user],
                "project" : $scope.projectsList[$scope.fields.project]
                };
...
```

Comment: it's finally working - thanks ! The only problem is that its not working with "{{user.name}} {{user.role}}" but with "{{user.name}}" - i think the key in the map must be the same as used in display - right?

Comment: You're right.  I edited the `$scope.usersList[]` assignment to include the role.

Comment: thanks but where  you edited it? i cant see the change in your answer ther is still: "$scope.usersList[response[i].name] "

Comment: thanks but then value="{{user}}" should be value="{{user.name}} {{user.role}}", shouldn't it? - but i think i got the point ;-)